# Local variables outside functions

Tags: netlogo

A good written code would be easier to read, so I would like to write my code in the nicest possible way. In order to do this, I would need to move some code inside functions. 
In this case I have defined a local variable outside, that should be called and used in the function:

```
let postman nobody

ask one-of turtles [
          set postman my-postman
          set shape "person"

      ; CHECK IF THERE IS ANY EMAIL FOR ME  - function from here
      if empty? mailbox [
        let this-mail self

      hatch-mail 1[
        hide-turtle
        set person postman
        set this-mail self
       ... ; omitted for brevity
   ]
]
```

I would like to improve the reading of the code moving the part of checking the mailbox into a function. However, some part of code depends on postman, i.e. a local variable defined outside.

What would the right way be to create such a function, taking into account this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to use what are termed 'arguments' in procedures, where some information gets passed. In the following version of the code, the `self` turtle is passed to the procedure and, within that procedure, is referred to as #turtle (the name is arbitrary, but I use # at the start to make it obvious that it's coming from the procedure argument.

```
ask one-of turtles
[ set postman my-postman
  set shape "person"
  if empty? mailbox [ do-something self ]
]

to do-something [#parent]  ; observer procedure
  ask #parent
  [ hatch-mail 1
    [ hide-turtle
      set person [my-postman] of #parent    ; or of myself, since #parent did the asking
      set this-mail self
       ... ; omitted for brevity
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hi JenB. The problem is that I am declaring a local variable that is called in the ask one-of. What I should put into a function is `if empty? mailbox [
      ... ; omitted code for brevity
   ]`, where I also call that variable. The variable postman is defined locally as at each tick the turtle's neighbours change. If it was global or defined as turtles-own, I could do what you did

Comment: Thank you JenB. Would it be the same to define a local variable as global, in order to use it in the procedure?

Comment: Try it out and see what happens. Think about whether the answer depends on it being a local variable.